# Powershell to C#

Tags: c#, arrays, powershell, converters

I'm working with a powershell script to try and convert it to a C# program but I have come across a problem I am struggling with. The script uses `$NameExample = @()`, which I believe is just an empty array in C# - Something like `decimal[] NameExample = new decimal[] {}`.

Here is more of the code to help but I am mainly trying to figure out how to declare `$NameExample = @()` as a C# array variable, anything will help! Thanks

```
$counter = 0
$UnitAvgerage = 20

$NameExample=@()
$NameExample2=@()

while ($counter -lt $NameExample.Count) 
{
    $NameExample2 += $NameExample[$counter..($counter+$UnitAvg -1)] | measure-object -average
    $counter += $NameExample2
}
```

Comment: Instead of converting your code line by line it would be better to first just understand what you want to achieve. Chances are this is easy to rewrite in C#

Comment: That Powershell arrays are being appended by new items in the loop. On C# proper you'll want `List` instead

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_arrays.php

Comment: That is poor PowerShell code to begin with, because arrays are actually of fixed size and `+=` has to reallocate on every loop iteration. As previous commenter wrote, don't use raw arrays in C# and use one of the collection types that are optimized for frequent append operations, like `System.Collections.Generic.List`.

Comment: if your concern is the type of the array, using `dynamic` object may be the solution. you may declare the array as: `var NameExample = new List<dynamic>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are *fixed-size* data structures, so they cannot be built up *iteratively*.

PowerShell makes it *seem* like that is possible with `+=`, but what it does behind the scenes is to create a *new* array every time, comprising the original elements plus the new one(s).

This is quite inefficient and to be avoided, even in PowerShell code (as convenient as it is) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).

Therefore, in your C# code use an array-*like* (list) type that you can build up *efficiently*, such as [`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

// ... 

// Create a list that can grow.
// If your list must hold objects of different types, use new List<object>()
var nameExample= new List<int>();

// ... use .Add() to append a new element to the list.
nameExample.Add(42);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MidnightBlueKnight; my pleasure.